# MAMP Change Document Root Requires re-import of sql database

Tags: drupal-7, innodb, mamp

I develop on a Mac (High Sierra) with MAMP (basic, not Pro), and I have several different Drupal sites in `~/Sites/<sitename>`.

Currently, if I change Document Root to work on a different site, I get errors on the new site until I delete the database `.frm` and `.ibd` files, as well as the log/data files, and re-import the database from a SQL dump.

Errors are:

> 2019-11-04T20:01:50.231324Z 2 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table
>   /cache_bootstrap from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB
>   though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for
>   how to resolve the issue.

Files I have to delete:

```
/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57/<sitename>/ (entire contents)
ibdata1
ib_logfile0
ib_logfile1
```

Re-importing the SQL database each time I want to work on a different site is getting really old. It is not a crisis, since this is just local development and it's not impacting the server, but it is seriously annoying. Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: It does not require what you ended up doing.  However, there are not enough details on what you _did do_ to debug it.

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't be necessary- but this is impacting 5 or 6 different sites, and although they are all Drupal 7, they are different versions with some php 5.6 and some 7.2.  Some are innodb, and some are mysql.  Which details would be helpful?